# Where is the CG on the Lockheed Model 10-A Electra?

Tags: cg, lockheed

I'd like to know where the centre of gravity on the Lockheed 10-A Electra is located (I am unable to find this information anywhere online). An image would also be very helpful!

Comment: It varies depending on how the airplane is loaded (fuel, cargo, etc.).

Comment: And that's your answer...  (CG is normally around 1/4 of the chord length back from the leading edge BTW.)

Answer (score 2):

As @757toga says, “It varies”  But [here](https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5e25b3811195f14156e54b35/t/5ef0dfabc03f0766ae29548b/1592844262115/eal-188+2+Limits.pdf) is an Electra flight manual with a Center of Gravity chart which a pilot would use to determine the CG for a given flight.

[image: Section 2-1 page 3]